# How to store geohashed data with high performance

Tags: c#, azure, geospatial, azure-table-storage, key-value-store

I want to keep geodata (latitude/longitude) objects in a table storage and also in memory.

With geohash you can divide the whole world into 32 sections. Each section can also devided into 32 sections and so on. This can be done up to 12 times (levels).

(See this for geohash http://www.bigdatamodeling.org/2013/01/intuitive-geohash.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)

For exaple: 
57.64911,10.40744 (location in Denmark) --> u4pruydqqvj

1. For storing these data in a table storage like Azure Tables, what
   would be a best practice for choosing partition and row key?
2. For storing such data in memory, what would here be the best
   practice? I could use one big Dictionary with the geohash code as
   the key. That would be a very large Disctionary. I could also use
   nested Dictionaries with 12 levels. In this approach I have 32
   Dictionaries in first level. Each has a geohash with just one
   character and so on.

The target is, to find all geodata objects at a given level with high performance.

**EDIT:**

I have a given geohash code. The given code can be of any geohash level or section. E.g. u, u4, u4p or u4pr. With the code I want to find:

- Total number of geodata objects within that section.
- Total number of geodata objects of a specific categorie within that section.
- At a lower level all geodata objects.

I'm looking for a best practice to store such data once in a table storage and once in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Table Storage is all about how you store the data for querying later - because, for high performance, you have to use partition key (for small sets of data - not 1000s) and row key - which will only return one row. From your edit, I think you will need to look at duplicating your data for proper storage and querying.

There are so many ways you can do this that we could go on for hours. However, consider the following when you look for a solution:

- You can store JSON in a column to hold multiple data
- Each row can have its own schema
- A TABLE is a type of partition - you could
  feasibly have a table per "level" or per category

Some examples to illustrate

TABLE: GEO_COUNTS

```
pk     rk          data
-------------------------------
u      total       568965
u      cat:bars    41526
u      cat:gas     35689
u4     total       988965
u4     cat:bars    55526
u4     cat:gas     22689
```

TABLE: GEO_COUNTS

```
pk     rk          data (JSON)
-------------------------------
u      unique id   {"total":568965, categories: ["bars" :41526, "gas":95689 ]}
u4     unique id   {"total":568965, categories: ["bars" :41526, "gas":95689 ]}
```

TABLE: GEO_DETAILS

```
pk     rk          data
-------------------------------
u      unique_id   ...
u      unique_id   ...
u4     unique_id   ...
u4     unique_id   ...
```

TABLE: GEO_DETAILS_U

```
pk     rk          data
-------------------------------
u4     unique_id   ...
u4     unique_id   ...
u4p    unique_id   ...
u4p    unique_id   ...
```

TABLE: GEO_DETAILS_U_CATEGORY_BARS

```
pk     rk          data
-------------------------------
u4     unique_id   ...
u4     unique_id   ...
u4p    unique_id   ...
u4p    unique_id   ...
```

Comment: Ok, to get really good performance I have to store the data related to the query. That means I have to duplicate the data. Would DocumentDB be a better choice regarded to performance issues?

Comment: You'd have to check, I have not looked into Document DB too much. It does have indexing (custom and automatic) which would help. However, it is much more expensive.